# Deploy Django app (using Celery) to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I am a beginner in web app development. <(__)>
I am developing an app with Celery in Django, and I want to deploy it to Heroku, but it doesn't work.
It was working fine in my local environment, but... (sad...)

I would appreciate it if you could tell me in detail how to configure the minimum required files ("settings.py", "Procfile", etc.) so that I can deploy without errors!
("REDIS_URL" is obtained by Heroku add-on...)

I tried the following after researching on the Internet and watching videos, but after deploying the application, the "task result" in the database did not return any results.

・【settings.py】
Change "CELERY_BROKER_URL" to the URI obtained from the Heroku add-on

・【Procfile】
Add the following
「worker celery worker -A project.celery -l INFO」

・【celery.py】
As follows

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

・【tasks.py】
Same as local, with "@shared_task" prefixed to the function

Comment: _but after deploying the application, the "task result" in the database did not return any results._. Did it deploy successfully? What do you see in logs? There may be some more helpful information